# Add a friend with iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, request, addition, friend

I'm working hard to find out a way to send a friendship request
to a Facebook user using the iOS Facebook SDK (v.3.2). But it seems
the SDK does not provide the API to do that.

Anyone could tell me why Facebook decided this strategy with iOS and 
not with Blackberry since I'm able to send friendship request with my 
Blackberry phone ?

Or maybe I'm not able to find out a solution with the iOS SDK. Could
anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why Facebook decided on this strategy. But one can reasonably assume it stems from the fact that Friend Requests are an incredibly sensitive feature. Programmatically sending friend requests could create some PR nightmares. Not sure, just my 2 cents.

And what app on Blackberry allows you to send friend requests? The official Facebook App, of course. But to my knowledge it's not possible in 3rd party apps. This isn't an iOS isolated strategy, its across the board.

Only work-around I can see is have them login in a WebView. Hide that webview, but when they want to add someone as a friend, open that WebView and point it to the url of the person they want to add.